# Next.js Typescript Project Custom Link Button Proptype

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

My project has a custom `Button` component and a `NextLink` wrapper that passes the `href` down to the button. I want to combine these two components for cleanliness' sake, but something goes wrong when I combine the props for each. I am unable to spread `rest` in the prop destructuring statement.  I get a TypeScript error saying:

> Rest types may only be created from object types.ts(2700)

Whenever I *remove* (or comment out) `size: 'xs' | 's' | 'm' | 'l' | 'xl'`, the error disappears.  So my question is obviously, is something wrong with my `size` type?  Is this a bug? Component follows.

```
import NextLink, { LinkProps } from 'next/link'
import { HTMLProps, FC } from 'react'
import { GlobalColorsType } from '../../types'
import Button from './Button'

type ButtonProps = {
  type: GlobalColorsType
  size: 'xs' | 's' | 'm' | 'l' | 'xl'
  onClick: () => void
  className?: string
  id?: string
  style?: any
}

type LinkButtonProps = ButtonProps & LinkProps & HTMLProps<HTMLAnchorElement>

const LinkButton: FC<LinkButtonProps> = ({
  as,
  children,
  href,
  replace,
  scroll,
  shallow,
  passHref,
  ...rest
}) => (
  <NextLink
    as={as}
    href={href}
    passHref={passHref}
    replace={replace}
    scroll={scroll}
    shallow={shallow}
  >
    <a {...rest}>
      <Button ...ButtonProps/>
    </a>
  </NextLink>
)

export default LinkButton
```

Comment: TypeScript issue aside, this line is not valid syntax: `<Button ...ButtonProps/>`.

Answer (score 0):

The `HTMLProps` type includes all the possible attributes that every HTML element can have. You should use `AnchorHTMLAttributes` instead, which provides anchor-specific props, and further narrows down the props type.

```js
type LinkButtonProps = ButtonProps & LinkProps & AnchorHTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>
```

If the above doesn't cover all the attributes you need for the anchor element, you can use `ComponentProps<'anchor'>` instead.

```js
type LinkButtonProps = ButtonProps & LinkProps & ComponentProps<'anchor'>
```